# Cascading parameters not working as expected

Tags: sql, reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2008, cascading

I have a report with 4 parameters which need to be populated automatically when a report opens.

[image: Cascading Parameters]

2 parameters work fine but Lecturer parameter is not selecting any values.

Queries:

```
Year:
SELECT REGT_Year
FROM CurrentAttendance_New

CourseType:
SELECT DISTINCT CourseType
FROM            CurrentAttendance_New
WHERE        (REGT_Year = @Year)

Lecturer:
SELECT DISTINCT LectName
FROM            CurrentAttendance_New
WHERE        (CourseType IN (@CourseType))
ORDER BY LectName

        Register:

        SELECT DISTINCT Class_Register COLLATE 
    DATABASE_DEFAULT + ' - ' + Register_Title 
    COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT + ' - ' + 
    Register_Day COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT + '  ' + 
    CONVERT(char(5),StartTime, 108) + ' - ' 
        + CONVERT(char(5), EndTime, 108) AS Register
        FROM            CurrentAttendance_New
        WHERE         (REGT_Year = @Year) 
AND (CourseType IN (@CourseType)) 
AND (LectName IN (@Lecturer))   (LectName IN (@Lecturer))
```

[image: Available values]

[image: Default Values]

Any idea where am I going wrong?

Comment: If they are getting populated but are not getting selected, then look to add a Default value.

Comment: @Roberto - Yes I am adding default values in all the parameters..

Comment: Can you verify the default value exists in the dataset returned by the query?

Comment: @Roberto - Yes, I am using parameter in my main dataset - see above Register

Comment: Hello, If you are still having this problem. Can you verify that the `Lecturer` dataset returns no NULL values? A NULL value can prevent it from selecting Defaults.

Comment: Roberto I am sure the dataset has no NULL values

Comment: Only other thing i could say to try is to check the order of both the parameters and datasets. Meaning, to make sure that your paramaters are ordered `Year, CourseType, Lecturer, Register` and the datasets are made in that same order. In your first screenshot i see that the `Lecturer` dataset is before the `CourseType`.

Comment: @Roberto - Yes they are in order

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that in your Lecturer query you're using an "in" statement, but you're passing it a single string of values which won't exist (you are probably Joining the values of the parameter for that). One option is to use a Split function to pass all the Course Types into it. This can be done in the query or as a DataSet filter. There are several posts out there if you search for that, but this should at least point you in the right direction.